# Apache config in sites-enabled not being detected?

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd

I'm trying to set up my new Redhat server and I have Apache config in my /etc/httpd/sites-enabled folder, but when I run `/usr/sbin/httpd -S` as root to check the syntax, it just returns:

```
    [root@511863-web3 sites-enabled]# /usr/sbin/httpd -S
    VirtualHost configuration:
    Syntax OK
```

So it doesn't look like it's detecting it. Since it's a new server, am I missing some sort of configuration? I restarted httpd, but my site still doesn't work.

Comment: You say this is a Redhat server, but you're using a directory called 'sites-enabled'... are you sure you're using RHEL?  That's a debian/ubuntu-style directory structure, and won't do anything on RHEL.  RHEL systems can have configuration fragments in /etc/httpd/conf.d, however.

Answer (score 4):

Your main config (httpd.conf or apache2.conf) should have a line that will include the sites-enabled directory.

```
# Include the virtual host configurations: 
Include sites-enabled/
```

If it is not there, add it near the end, and reload apache.

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow some steps, like there must be one more directory named as sites-available in /etc/httpd. So you need to create a file with any name in sites-available and then you need to run below command. No need to use .conf as an extension for this file.

```
$ a2ensite (your file name)
```

for example, suppose you have created a file named as abc then your command must be

```
$ a2ensite abc
```

This command will create a symbolic link in /etc/httpd/site-enabled directory. Then you can run a command to check syntax and get that site up on your browser.

Comment: I already have a symlink in my sites-enabled that points to that configuration file in my sites-available.